# Error while installing Zend Server

Tags: zend-server

Everything went fine except,

```
 chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink `/usr/local/zend/var/log/access.log'
 chmod: cannot operate on dangling symlink `/usr/local/zend/var/log/error.log'
```

I simply installed Linux, and tried installing Zend Server on a completely fresh Fedora 14 installation. Everything went "Ok" till it hit that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question that could probably be better answered on the Zend Forums at http://forums.zend.com/viewforum.php?f=8&sid=e32efa1d3c93806bcd96a2d98a3922f9